# How to order the time and date column in my MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I would like to formulate my query so that I can achieve the expected output stated below. I tried to achieve the expected output but I'm always getting the actual output that is also depicted below.

I'm using MySQL as my RDBMS.

**Ordering Rule:**

The ordering rule is all about displaying in sequence each set of time period of each date. For example, September 23 - 26 [Display the first set of time periods] -> next display: September 23 - 26 [Display second set of time periods, if any] -> and so on.

**Expected Output:**

```
|      Date         | Start_Time | End_Time
|September 23, 2020 | 8:00 AM    | 9:00 AM
|September 24, 2020 | 9:00 AM    | 10:00 AM 
|September 25, 2020 | 8:00 AM    | 9:00 AM 
|September 26, 2020 | 9:00 AM    | 10:30 AM 
|September 23, 2020 | 9:00 AM    | 10:00 AM
```

**Actual Output:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9kWV.png

**Current Code:**

```
Select DISTINCT timeslot.Timeslot_ID,
timeslot.Date,timeslot.Start_Time,timeslot.End_Time from timeslot
WHERE timeslot.ExamEvent_ID=1 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE
(CONCAT(timeslot.Start_Time,' - ',timeslot.End_Time), '%l:%i %p - %l:%i %p'), 
STR_TO_DATE (timeslot.Date, '%M %e, %Y')
```

Comment: Order by Date,Start_Time,End_Time ?

Comment: Show an example of the query that you have already come up with yourself. And please don't put actual output on a different website, but post it here.

Comment: Please, describe the rule of ordering

Comment: what are the date, start_time and end_time fields types? It doesn't look like they are standard mysql formats

Comment: @Jelle I edited the content of my question. I added the current sql query and in terms of the actual output's display, It is an image that stack overflow doesn't allow me to post here due to it requires 10 reputational points thus I added only the link. Thank you

Comment: @astentx the rule of ordering is added to the content of the question; please let me know if it needs to be further explained or possible to achieve. Thank you

Comment: @LelioFaieta the type of your mentioned columns are varchar but it is converted to date whenever queried or requested from the server. It is customized by the developers so that to satisfy business requirements. If Its a bad practice, I'll provide a suggestion to my team about it. Thank you

Comment: @Emanuele I already tried this but it still doesn't achieve the specified expected output. Thank you

Comment: What is "time period"? You have `start_time` and `end_time`, and the latter is not a whole hour. Should they be considered in ordering? Also you describe: *Order each Date ASC but it needs to display the first time period, second time period, n time period... of each date accordingly*. But expected output looks like you need to order by time period first, and only then by date.

Comment: @astentx Start_TIme and End_Time is the time period that I'm pertaining about in my ordering rule. It can range from 30 minutes, a whole hour, 2 hours, and so on and it is part of the ordering. 

For the second matter, yes you're correct. I just miscommunicated it in my previous ordering rule thus I updated it, no changes made I just reconstructed it. I also tried to make a query where you order it by time period first and then by date but it didn't satisfied the expected output. I'm open though if a query with that kind of logic works.

Thank you :)

Comment: Order by timeslot.Start_Time, timeslot.End_Time, timeslot.Date then

Comment: @Emanuele I tried your suggestion but the output is the same as the "Actual Output" I described above it didn't satisfy the expected output. Thank you though :)

Comment: DAta in image and your sample are different. How did order change elements?

Comment: Create a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 with the table's definition and sample data to clarify your requirement.

Comment: @Emanuele I was in a hurry while making this question, pardon me, but I fixed it now. the row of data on the Expected and Actual Result is now paralleled. Thank you

Comment: @forpas [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7219a5a2ee511e597713c8408a8ed8df)

Here it is. I also included my current query code. Thank you

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas 8.0.3 is the current version that I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT Timeslot_ID, ExamEvent_ID, Date, Start_Time, End_Time
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Start_Time, '%l:%i %p')) rn
  FROM timeslot
) t  
ORDER BY rn, STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%M %e, %Y')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4520b1b089977f806b4513ba973b01ce).